# sorting search results in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm have a django app with the following model.

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    post =  models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="post_likes")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
```

To allow the users search for a particular blog and then display those objects I have the following view.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        search = request.GET.get("input")
        posts = Posts.objects.filter(category__icontains=f"{search}")
    else:
        posts = Posts.objects.all()
    params = {'blog': posts} 
    return render(request, 'index.html', params)
```

In the above view , variable `search` contains what user has searched for, that I'm receiving through a form.
But I also want to provide a sort functionality after user has searched for a blog. Like user searches for `"recipes"`, I need to show them all the search results and then let him sort them based on `likes` and `recent` etc. How do I do it since I'm losing search terms just after displaying the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the sort options are also part of the search form so you could also send the chosen sort option as a query parameter to the backend, just as you're doing with the search term:

```
sort = request.GET.get('sort')
# use the sort options to order your queryset as you desire
```

Comment: The sort options are not a part of search form, I want the user to be able to sort them after displaying them onto the screen.

Comment: I don't think the sort options being a part of the form would prevent you from doing that, you can have a default sort option initially selected send that to the backend if the user doesn't choose to change it.   


If that doesn't work for you, you could put the search term in the context, just as you're doing with the posts so you'll have access to it in the template.  


Another option is to enable the `django.template.context_processors.request` option in your `TEMPLATES` setting so you'll have access to the request object in the template so you can get the search term from there.